# binding lost in jquery using on

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pjax

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form[method="POST"]', function(event) {
alert();
});
```

Above code worked when I submit the form but it lost the binding after I do few [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) navigation.

I have no idea why it stop firing, it's placed the core script and I never refresh the page.

update:

I did an experiment binding click instead of submit

```
$(document).on('click','.test',function(){
      alert('click')
    })
```

It worked, but why it doesn't with submit?

Comment: Does `pjax` submit form ? Can include `pjax` portions of `js` at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 it doesn't matter with pjax

Comment: Something is unbinding your submit event or stopping submit event to propagate through document

Comment: @A.Wolff that must be pjax? have do I bind it back?

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler _"it doesn't matter with pjax "_ ? Not certain what "doesn't matter" ? Is form submitted using `$.ajax()` via `pjax` ?

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler Ya try to rebind it or investigate further the why event isn't fired as expected. Now i don't know pjax plugin, i've no idea what's going on. Other way would be instead of delegating event, try to capture it: `document.addEventListener(
    'submit',
    function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('form[method="POST"]')){ 
            alert('form submit called!');
        }
    },
    true /*Capture event*/
);`

Comment: @A.Wolff what does capture event do? It has no different I put an alert within my submit event

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler Capturing event is to avoid any propagation event issue. Now do you have any error in console? Any online link we can check it?

Comment: @A.Wolff can u tell which line of the code unbind my stuff? https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/blob/master/jquery.pjax.js

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler I'm not sure your event is unbound... I'm not sure what you are doing. Provide a MCVE. And just in doc, they use their own custom method for `submit`, isn't it what you are looking for? `$(document).on('submit', 'form[data-pjax]', function(event) {
  $.pjax.submit(event, '#pjax-container')
})`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) event

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
  // do stuff
})
```

Comment: Where I should use this? please explain more.

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler If `form` is submitted using `$.ajax()` an `ajaxComplete` event should be called at each `form` submission. Try substituting `ajaxComplete` event for `submit` event for handler to be called when `form` is submitted; see http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Comment: Where does this ajaxComplete be placed? the submit event happen before the ajax fire. Does ajaxComplete make sense here?

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler _"Where does this ajaxComplete be placed?"_ Same place where `$(document).on('submit'` is, after removing `$(document).on('submit'` . _"the submit event happen before the ajax fire."_ ? Why asked at comments above if `$.ajax()` submits `form` : _"Is form submitted using $.ajax() via pjax ?"_ : _"$.ajax"_ . Could alternatively use `ajaxStart` event or both `ajaxStart` and `ajaxComplete` events

Comment: you put $.ajax inside a submit event, not the other round.

Comment: @NicholeA.Miler _"you put $.ajax inside a submit event, not the other round."_ ? How is `form` submitted ? Is `form` submitted using `$.ajax()` ? Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate issue described at original Question ?

Comment: It can be nothing to do with ajax at all, the bind simply gone after I navigate the site which used pjax. http://pastebin.com/hjadYAFM

Comment: Where in `js` does site navigate to a different `url` ?

Comment: `$(document).pjax('a', {
            container: "#content",
            timeout: 12000
        });` With this one line code all links which originally were a native post/get, it use pjax.

Comment: Can this be reproduced at jsfiddle ? Note, not tried `pjax` before here

Comment: the problem is simple, pjax unbind my submit handler. https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/blob/master/jquery.pjax.js but I have no idea which line does that.

Comment: If can reproduce issue at jsfiddle or plnkr , would probably be helpful in determining a solution

Comment: I've found the problem. A clash of name. Sigh because I'm using on() globally, I have to refactor my classes name on its child. will requirejs solve helps to avoid such clashes?